# German Equivalent of my Ph.D. in Computer Engineering

Tags: united-states, germany, degree

I got my Ph.D. in Computer Engineering from an ECE Department at a US university and need a printout of my degree and institution from anabin.kmk.org. The institution I found. The degree I cannot find.

I went to "*Hochschulabschlüsse*" then "*Suchen nach Abschlüssen*" and chose "USA." I can either find "Doctor of Philosophy in Engineering" or "Doctor of Philosophy in Computer Science." The first has the University of Maryland as the "*Verleihende Institutionen*" and the other has the University of Illinois Urbana-Champaign. But my institution is none of the two.

It's unlikely that Germany recognizes the "Doctor of Philosophy" degree only if done at the University of Maryland. I must be doing (and/or understanding) something wrong.

Does anyone have experience with this database?

Comment: What do you need a "printout of my degree and institution from anabin.kmk.org" for exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anabin is a database that contains some historic informations about which degrees from which universities have been "analyzed" by a German bureaucrat. It is not complete.

Apparently, there is no record in the database of someone with a Ph.D. in CE from your university having their Ph.D. analyzed in this way. The reason likely is that there is no special state bureaucracy for computer engineers, unlike for say doctors, at least as far as I know.

So why do you need this anabin printout anyways? Can you perhaps tell whomever requested it that it is not available, since the database does not have every degree from every university?

Instead, if your university can be found in the database (at Suche nach Institutionen), there might be a note that a Ph.D. from it is, in general, considered equivalent to the German Doktorgrad in that field. This equivalence is usually granted if the university is ranked as a "research/doctoral university" with a "[very] high research activity" in the 2005 Carnegie rating.

If not, you might need to go through the motions and have the state bureaucracy (of the specific state where you want to work) review your degree in particular, so that it can be added to the database.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I found my university there as one of the "H+" ones. That should mean that the degrees from my university are recognized in Germany. A German friend also says that the printout for my university explicitly says that "Doctor of Philosophy" equates to German "Doktor."